# Auto generated ID from DB in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, lambda, autonumber

I have a primary key for my table employee. I named it "IDS".
The IDS data is like : K-00001, K-00002, etc.
what I want to ask is, how to made this IDS auto generate in ASP.NET, not using trigger or function in SQL?

I have done my code like this:

```
            DBRabbit _db = new DBRabbit();
            Employee k = new Employee();
            var row = (from r in _db.Employees
                       orderby r.IDS descending
                       select r).FirstOrDefault();
            var n = row.IDS.PadLeft(5, '0');    
            IDSText.Text = n.ToString();
```

And I'm stuck while think how to adding the 'n' to + 1.. because when I write like this:

```
var n = row.IDS.PadLeft(5, '0')+1;
```

(last record is K-00010)
the result is K-000101
how to make it K-00011 without changing DB or using SQL server script/queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You better make your IDS column auto incremented as James said. Also if you need to have another column for `K-00010`, `K-00011`,... I would suggest you to use a computed column with the following formula

```
'K-' + cast( right([IDS]+(100000),(5)) as varchar(5))
```

EDIT:
Formula corrected.

Comment: +1: Nice suggestion. What I particularly like is the ease of implementation. OP could implement this without screwing up the entire design.

Comment: Absolutely, this is effortless.

Comment: I have change it to auto increment, changing it to int then how to use that "cast" ? It's used on asp or sql server?

Comment: ye, it is an t-sql formula. Go to the design mode of your table and add a new column to it. Then in the `Column properties > Table designer > Computed column specifications > Formula. Past it there and save. You are done.

Comment: an error is coming... it's said: error validating the formula for column IDS

Comment: You are trying to add this formula to the IDS column. `You have to add a new column to the table and add above formula as I said before.`

Comment: now it's no errors, but nothing happened Mr. Kaf. It still 1, 2, 3, not K-00001, K-00002.. did I wrong or why?

Comment: Oh jeez, you must be doing it wrong. This is deadly simple if you read what I said very carefully and follow it. Again, Make your IDS column auto incremented column and forget about it. `Add another new column to your table` and add above formula to the new column as `Column properties > Table designer > Computed column specifications > Formula. Past it there and save`. if your new column name is myColumn then if you select myColumn in your query it will bring what you expect. ex, `SELECT IDS,myColumn FROM Employee`.

Comment: I'm sorry.. My fault.. I do that at the same column.. I didn't notice about new column.. Sorry.. my bad.. But really thanks about this, now it works!! thank you very much Kaf.. and thank you to teach me patiently :D

Answer (score 2):

Make the column auto-incrementing. As a rule of thumb, you should *never* increment primary keys manually -- that's just begging for issues. The right sequence of events would compromise that logic.

Comment: "Issues" being a nice way of saying "horrible-awful-painful-badthings." +1 =)

Comment: Indeed lost count of the number of times I've seen this sort of thing done. It's just a screw up waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just have an auto inc integer somewhere (DB in preference) and then build your no doubt very meaningful representation with

```
String.Concat("K-",KeyValue.ToString().PadLeft(5,'0');
```

Your way is lot of messing about with an almost guaranteed chance for Murphy to play with your head. Just don't do what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var n = (Convert.ToInt32(row.IDS) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
```

Comment: Have to strip the K- off the front as well, he's doing the soon to go wrong "intelligent" number trick.

Answer (score 0):

are you using javascript for the above? if so try using

var n = (number(row.ids.substring(2))+1).toString().PadLeft(5,'0')

the substirng function is to remove the "k-"